# secure boot problems

Tags: boot

As I understand elementary is compatible with secure boot. However, I wasn't able to boot from usb without disabling secure boot, and now that the os is installed, it will only boot with secure boot disabled (it does not recognize elementary as authorized). It does seem that boot/efi was created on install. I used "erase disk and install elementary" option. What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Secure Boot will not allow you to boot a Live USB. And to boot Elementary in Secure Boot after install, you need to set your BIOS Secure Boot option to SETUP MODE. This way, Elementary will be added as Authorized automatically and it will boot. Just worked for me. Check it out and let me know.